# Finding line and column number in a long java string

Tags: java, string

In Java, given a multi-line string and a character index within that string (e.g. the result of a matcher.start() call), what's the most efficient way of finding that character index's line and column number in the string?

For example

```
String s = "abc\ndef\nghi\n";
int i = 5; // i.e. the e character (since we start at 0 and count newlines)

// Do something

System.out.println("Line: " + line + " Column: " + column);
```

Should produce

```
Line: 2 Column 2
```

---

The code I inherited for this uses `s.substring(p)` to get the prefix of the string up to the character index, splits that on newlines, then counts number of lines returned by split, and the number of characters in the final array element returned by split. That works correctly, but becomes slow as that prefix becomes long (and I want to use it in a tight loop).

Comment: show us what you have done.

Comment: calculate once and then store it in `HashMap<Character, Position>`

Comment: I think you mean something more like HashMap<Integer index, Position>, or better yet, ArrayList<Position>, but yes, this is what I ended up with (since I was running many times on the same input).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you need to use substring and generate new strings and tokenize the piece when you can just iterate over the original string and avoid any object allocation?

```
int c = 1;
int line = 1, col = 1;
while (c <= i) 
{
  if (string.charAt(c) == '\n')
  {
    ++line;
    col = 1;
  } else {
    ++col;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep, I like it, and it's certainly what I'll do unless there's something quicker I don't know about.

Comment: Quicker than searching up to `i` for the amount of new line characters? I don't think there is a way to count them which doesn't imply at least **O(n)**, since you need to know how many there are. And once you reached the last `\n` before the given index you must be sure there is not another one before the specified index.

Comment: You forgot to increment `c`.  I think a for loop would be easier.

Comment: What about tab characters? They could take anywhere from 1 to 4 columns of width. I am sure there are other Unicode characters that could also have width's other than 1.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code

```
String s = "abc\ndef\nghi\n";
    String tokens[]=s.split("\n");
    for(String tok:tokens)
    {
        System.out.println(tok);
    }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple implementation on Kotlin from scratch
It seems to work. I would be glad if it is useful to someone

```
@Throws(IllegalStateException::class)
fun String.getLineCol(position: Int): Pair<Int, Int> {
    check(position in 0..lastIndex)
    var line = 0
    var col = 0
    var i = 0
    while (i < position) {
        val newLine = indexOf('\n', i)
        if (newLine < 0 || position <= newLine) {
            col = position - i
            break
        }
        i = newLine + 1
        line++
    }
    return line + 1 to col + 1
}
```